# How can I use WifiManager in a non-activity class?

Tags: java, android

I have two classes: one of these is an activity class and the other is non-activity. And I call a method which is inside the non-activity class for returning mac Adress.

activity class:

```
public class Control extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    deneme d = new deneme(this); // i has tried (getApplicatonContext)
    String x = d.macadress();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

and non-activity class:

```
public class deneme {
Context mcontext ;
WifiManager wm;

public deneme(Context mcontext){
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
}

public String macadress(){
    wm = (WifiManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    String m_szWLANMAC = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
    return m_szWLANMAC;

}}
```

but the method return null. I have the permission ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.

Comment: Is the Wifi connection _active_ when you run your code?

Answer (score 3):

if your wifi is not enable on the device , it will return null as your case , check if the wifi is enabled then if its enabled return the mac address else notify the user to enable the wifi .

```
package com.example.wifitest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TEST {
    Context mcontext;
WifiManager wm;

public TEST(Context mcontext) {
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
}

public String macadress() {
    wm = (WifiManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
        String m_szWLANMAC = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
        return m_szWLANMAC;
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Please enbale your wifi",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your reply. you're right.I did't know emulator use 3g internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        deneme d = new deneme(getApplicationContext()); 
  //  String x=d.wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();


      String x = d.macadress();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
 class deneme {
Context mcontext ;
WifiManager wm;

public deneme(Context mcontext){
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
}

public String macadress(){
    wm = (WifiManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    String m_szWLANMAC = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
    return m_szWLANMAC;

}}
```

I didn't run the code but this is hw its to be done

Comment: firstly,thanks for your reply, but the project has stopped when i changed the code according to what you said.

Comment: please go through the updated code i debugged it and its running fine.... its giving me the required result.

Comment: 64:A7:69:AF:60:B9 i got my macaddress from the above code while debugging

Comment: thanks my friend, the code did not work emulator because of no wifi connection and then works my android telephone.

Comment: did it wrk with ur device?.. if yes then was pleasure 2 help u out. and tick it  right if u found the solution wrking.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the `Context` of that `Activity` to that `non-Activity` class.

**Here is a snippet from net :**

```
Class conectivityManager

Context myContext;

public conectivityManager(Context cxt){

myContext = cxt

}

public startWifi(){

//start-wifi

}
```

**See this link :**

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/htc/articles/75491.aspx

Comment: Well, that is _exactly_ what is already done in the code, except the saved context is called `this.mcontext` instead of `myContext`.